# How to encode json and special characters from php to javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

In my db I save the json in a custom field called `usp-custom-12` like this:

```
[{&quot;Mamma&quot;:[&quot;Papa&quot;]}]
```

Then I try to decode that

```
<?php
  $jsonTable = usp_get_meta(false, 'usp-custom-12');
?>
var data = <?php echo htmlspecialchars_decode($jsonTable); ?>;
```

But it is giving me

```
 var data = "[{"Mamma":["Papa"]}]";
```

And a console log error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

The full code:

```
<?php
  $jsonTable = usp_get_meta(false, 'usp-custom-12');
?>
var data = "<?php echo htmlspecialchars_decode($jsonTable); ?>";

console.log(data);

data = JSON.parse (data);
data.forEach(obj => {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
    $('#newTable thead tr').append($('<th>').text(key));

    obj[key].forEach((e, i) => {
      if(!$("#newTable tbody tr:eq("+i+")").length) $("<tr>").appendTo($("#newTable tbody"));
      $("#newTable tbody tr:eq(" + i + ")").append($('<td>').text(e))
    })
  })
});
```

In this jsFiddle if you click **save table** you will see it generates a table identical to the top one, that's also logging in console the correct json: https://jsfiddle.net/fbh0o67o/74/

Comment: Why are you storing `&quot;` in your database, instead of `"`? Stop that nonsense.

Comment: @CBroe regardless of the reason why, which I could convert it before saving it indeed, I was just wondering why this wasn't working...

Comment: there are legitimate reasons for html encoding a json string, i do it sometimes when i'm storing stuff in a data- attribute. typically wouldn't store it long term like that tho.

Comment: tbh it is a wordpress plugin which is storing data with special characters like that, I could indeed convert it before storing but since it isn't the biggest issue and I don't want neither to modify the plugin, I leave it like that and simply use the answers on here to resolve the echo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$jsonTable` contains a JSON string with html entities encoded, since it's already JSON, you just have to decode the html etities and echo it as is. No JSON decoding is required, no quoting is required. Just HTML decode and echo it into your javascript.

```
var data = <?php echo htmlspecialchars_decode(usp_get_meta(false, 'usp-custom-12')); ?>;

data.forEach(obj => {
   // Loop stuff here...
});
```

Comment: yup, that's beautiful, even more simplified as you've placed all in one line. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

The issue is with the quotes inside the string `"mama"` you need to escape those quotes using `addslashes` method.

Try using the following:

```
var data = "<?php echo addslashes(htmlspecialchars_decode($jsonTable)); ?>";
```

Comment: @Occam'sRazor Just below that he is doing JSON.parse to parse string into JSON.

Comment: exactly, I am doing the JSON.parse afterwards.. will accept in a minute. Just that I know, what was it wrong what I was doing?

Comment: yep, my bad. +1. i didn't expect him to convert the data from a string to json, back to a string, and then back into json.. didn't see that coming.. should have read closer..

Comment: @Occam'sRazor yup it is a very weird and long way actually what I am doing, could you guys help me simplify that?

Comment: @rob.m Actually when you echo string from php to javascript with double quotes in it, thus a string starting with double quotes and having double quotes in it breaks the JS. 

` "[{"Mamma":["Papa"]}]"` and javascript complains about it. if it was like this:  `"[{'Mamma':['Papa']}]"`

Comment: @rob.m yes the best method  would be use json_encode and then do the JSON.parse() rather than echo the response.

Comment: so is there a way i could simplify?

Comment: @rob.m - all you need to do is remove the quotes around the echo like i mentioned in my answer and then remove the js line that parses is as json. it's already JSON, you don't need to parse it unless you turn it into a string. this would be a great question for codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Occam'sRazor I agree.

Comment: no, you don't need to json encode it. just echo it as is, without the surounding quotes.

Comment: @Occam'sRazor ok let me give it a try your way then, didn't see to remove the PARSE

Comment: @Occam'sRazor thing is I would still need to convert `&quot;`

Comment: @rob.m - correct.. `var data = <?php echo htmlspecialchars_decode($jsonTable); ?>;` then comment out/remove the line with JSON.parse

Comment: @Occam'sRazor I have tried that before, and it gives me `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` the only way it is working is to use the code in this answer

Comment: @Occam'sRazor actually hang on, you're correct. I had left `$jsonTable = json_encode($jsonTable);` removing that works! Thanks a lot

Comment: @rob.m - glad you got it simplified. future developers will thank you.

Comment: @Occam'sRazor could you place that into an answer for future devs? I could do it myself but the solution is yours, this is the code:     `<?php
      $jsonTable = usp_get_meta(false, 'usp-custom-12');
    ?>
    var data = <?php echo htmlspecialchars_decode($jsonTable); ?>;`

Comment: @Occam'sRazor yes that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

**JSON to PHP:**

```
json_decode($string);
```

If you use the optional parameter `$assoc` as `true` - `json_decode($string, true)` will return associative array on success.

**PHP to JSON:**

```
json_encode($array);
```

PHP manuals:
[json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/bg/function.json-encode.php)
[json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/bg/function.json-decode.php)